# Query results in knex in mysql workbench do not converge

Tags: mysql, node.js

I think this is caused by the behavior of knex itself. How to solve this problem?

Result in workbench:

[image: result in workbench]

Result in knex:

[image: result in nodejs with knex]

Procedure code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `leaveClan`(in userId int)
BEGIN
set @rights = 0;
set @clanId = 0;
set @members = 0;
select @rights := `right`, @clanId := clans_id from clans_members
where accounts_id = userId limit 1;
select @members := count(*) from clans_members
where clans_members.clans_id = @clanId;
if @rights = 3 and @members > 1 then
select 'not-leave-full-clan' as 'error';
else 
DELETE FROM `senpa`.`clans_members`
WHERE accounts_id = userId;
if @members = 1 then
DELETE FROM `senpa`.`clans`
WHERE id = @clanId;
end if;
select 'clans-start-show' as 'success';
end if; 
END
```

Nodejs code with knex module:

```
const leaveClan = async function(userId) {
    const result = await db.raw('call senpa.`leaveClan`(?);', [userId]);

    console.log(result[0][0])
    return result[0][0];
}

leaveClan(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by stripping all select conditions and this error no longer occurs.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `leaveClan`(in userId int)
BEGIN
set @clanRight = 0;
set @clanId = 0;
set @members = (select count(*) from clans_members
where clans_members.clans_id = @clanId);

select `right`, clans_id into @clanRight, @clanId from clans_members
where accounts_id = userId limit 1;

if @clanId = 0 then
select 'user-already-leave' as 'error';
elseif @clanRight = 3 and @members > 1 then
select 'user-not-leave-full-clan' as 'error';
else
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DELETE FROM `senpa`.`clans_members`
WHERE accounts_id = userId;
if @members <= 1 then
DELETE FROM `senpa`.`clans_invitations`
WHERE clans_id = @clanId;
DELETE FROM `senpa`.`clans`
WHERE id = @clanId;
end if;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
select 'user-leave' as 'success';
end if; 
END
```